# Compare offset().top with object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a 'scrollSpy' type function. I don't know how to compare an argument against some values in an object, and return the (numerically) highest value's name.

I have some markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="a"></a></li>
    <li><a href="b"></a></li>
    <li><a href="c"></a></li>
    <li><a href="d"></a></li>
    <li><a href="e"></a></li>
    <li><a href="f"></a></li>
</ul>

<section id="a" class="scrollspy"></section>
<section id="b" class="scrollspy"></section>
<section id="c" class="scrollspy"></section>
<section id="d" class="scrollspy"></section>
<section id="e" class="scrollspy"></section>
<section id="f" class="scrollspy"></section>
```

And some script that creates an object consisting of each `section` and its distance in px from top:

```
var obj = {
    sectionOffset: {},
    scrollSpy: function (scrolled) {
        // This should look in the object with the offset values, and from all
        // the values that (scrolled) is higher than, take the largest, and
        // return its name.
    }
}


$(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        obj.scrollSpy($(document).scrollTop()); 
    });

    // Create an object consisting of all elements I want to 'spy' on.
    // Names and values are made of element ID and top offset respectively.
    $('.scrollspy').each(function () {
        obj.sectionOffset[$(this).attr('id')] = (parseInt($(this).offset().top));
    });

});
```

After I loop through the elements I want, it produces an object like:

```
{
    d: 5195,
    b: 3245,
    a: 1319,
    f: 5682,
    c: 2139,
    e: 3343
}
```

Just to be clear, if the user scrolls 3000px down the page, the function should return `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollSpy: function (scrolled) {

    var highest = 0, highestName = null;

    // iterate through the offsets
    $.each(obj.sectionOffset, function(name, val) {
        // check that scrolled is higher than the value, and that it's the highest found so far
        if (scrolled > val && val > highest) {
            highest = val;
            highestName = name;
        }
    });

    return highestName;
}
```

Comment: I was going to try converting the object to an array, then sorting it from highest to lowest and comparing the scrolled value against that. You've saved me the trouble, because this works just fine! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.scrollspy').each(function () 
{
    if(($(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) > 0)
    {
       //this is the one you are looking for.

       return false; //break the loop.
    }
});
```

this will work like scrollSpy [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/PfKJL/2/)

Comment: Are you sure? I ran this in `$(window).scroll()` and it gave me _all_ the `.scrollspy` elements. It seems as though you're comparing each element's height+offset with 0. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: if div's top is not viible by scrolling it's top will be in negative. so top + height > 0, still it is in visible. invisible div's top + height will be less than zero. so the first div that has (top + height) > 0 is what you needed.

Comment: Interesting idea, but when I log each offset, the values don't change when I scroll.

Comment: no this should work. $(this).offset().top. Better fiddle, what you are trying.

Comment: Not sure why you don't believe me :-/ [Here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/PfKJL/).

Comment: Sidenote: `return`ing from the `each` won't break the loop, you have to `return false`.

Comment: it is not meant that i don't belive. i tried to help you. see this [fiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/PfKJL/1/). Because yesterday only, i tried this one.

Comment: Ah. The difference is that your elements are wrapped in that `div`, so it's not measuring `.offset().top` from the same place.

Comment: section also working you can try by wrapping sections inside div.